# Mostrar listagem de 6 em 6 itens

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma listagem de menu com o seguinte HTML:

```css
.menu ul {
  height: 115px;
  width: 960x;
}
.menu li {
  font: 900 22px/22px"open sans";
  color: #16232e;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="/paginaSYS">
        <h4>tituloMenuSYS</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/paginaSYS">
        <h4>tituloMenuSYS</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/paginaSYS">
        <h4>tituloMenuSYS</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/paginaSYS">
        <h4>tituloMenuSYS</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/paginaSYS">
        <h4>tituloMenuSYS</h4>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

São seis itens, o que o designer me pediu foi, quando um sétimo item for cadastrado, e o usuário clicar na flecha para baixo, ele deve mostrar mais uma listagem com seis itens (mesmo que vá mostrar apenas um). Conforme essa imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, clicou na flecha pra baixo, ele mostra a próxima listagem com seis itens.
Tentei usar o Jcaroulsellite, com o vertical, mas não rolou, existe alguma outra solução?
O efeito tem que ser de passar de "cima para baixo" e  não de "esquerda para direita".

Comment: Seu menu é montado dinamicamente?

Comment: Faça com que os 6 itens some um valor fixo, por exemplo esse menu possui 800px, logo cada botão teria uma largura de aproximadamente 133px, e faça com que o botão de avançar movimente a div em 800px para esquerda/direita.

Comment: Exato, ele será gerenciável.

Comment: @FelipeStoker, acredito que você deve ter N elementos `UL`, cada um deles com 1 a 6 `LI`, por default apenas o primeiro sera exibido, e as setas irá alterar a visibilidade das `UL` (paginação)

Comment: @TobyMosque na verdade eu terei uma `UL` com **N** `li`s.

Comment: @FelipeStoker algo semelhante a isso certo? http://jsfiddle.net/bw48kft3/

Comment: @DiegoVieira isso, na verdade, a única coisa diferente, seria o menu fazer o efeito vertical, indo de cima pra baixo.

Comment: Achei uma solução para você, vou colocar como resposta;

Comment: Então é mais fácil ainda, mandarei a correção.

Comment: @DiegoVieira ah, eu mudei para `top: "-=200"` e funfou :D

Comment: @FelipeStoker basta fazer assim http://jsfiddle.net/bw48kft3/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ideia é fazer com que cada opção do menu (`<li>`) tenha um tamanho fixo tanto para largura como para a altura.

Obviamente pode fazer isso de forma dinâmica e fazer com que no `jQuery` pegue os valores e faça as devidas contas no código.

Nesse exemplo nossa opção deve possuir `113x40px`, e por fim fixamos o nosso menu com um tamanho de `800px`.

***Resultado***

```js
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#menu ul');
    
    $('.prox').click(function(){
        menu.animate({
            top: "-=40"
        }, 100);
    });
    
    $('.ante').click(function(){
        menu.animate({
            top: "+=40"
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

```css
#menu {
    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    width:113px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>MENU 1</li>
        <li>MENU 2</li>
        <li>MENU 3</li>
        <li>MENU 4</li>
        <li>MENU 5</li>
        <li>MENU 6</li>
        <li>MENU 7</li>
        <li>MENU 8</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button class='prox'>Proximo</button>
<button class='ante'>Anterior</button>
```

Basta implementar de acordo com suas exigências.

***UPDATE 2***

Adicionei alguns critérios para travar quando não houver mais opções.

```js
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#menu ul');
    var pos = 40;
    var limit;
    
    //Adicionar dinamicamente
    for(i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
        menu.append('<li>Menu #'+i+'</li>');
    
    limit = menu.height();
    
    $('.prox').click(function(){
        if(pos >= 0 && pos < limit) {
            menu.animate({
                top: "-=40"
            }, 100);
            
            pos += 40;
        }
    });
    
    $('.ante').click(function(){
        if(pos > 40 && pos <= limit) {
            menu.animate({
                top: "+=40"
            }, 100);
            
            pos -= 40;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
    width:610px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    height:40px;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
         
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="arrows">
    <button class='ante'>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>    
    </button>
    <button class='prox'>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta, mais há um problema na forma de bloquear quando não houver mais itens, se houverem mais de 12 itens ele irá travar os próximos, veja http://jsfiddle.net/davh8bfb/, acredito que seria melhor travar comparando com o primeiro elemento. Outro problema é que a cada `animate` ele sobe ou desce `2px` a mais deixando o menu desalinhado, alterei algumas coisas como sugestão se quiser incluir na resposta, veja aqui http://jsfiddle.net/bhrrk3x9/2/

Comment: @abfurlan Obrigado por avisar sobre o erro, corrigido e editado.

Answer (score 3):

Para uma paginação criada dinamicamente e sem numeração (somente botão próxima e anterior) você pode usar **Jquery Easy Paginate**.

**Segue um pequeno exemplo (Você pode alterar o css como desejar também, ou até mesmo o plugin para gerar de acordo com as class id's que você gostaria):** (http://jsfiddle.net/zgd56b1s/1/)

```js
/* http://cssglobe.com/lab/easypaginate/js/easypaginate.min.js */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#items').easyPaginate({
      step: 3,
      numeric: false
    });
    $('li.prev').html('').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $('li.next').html('').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

```css
ul#items {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul#items li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #FF5677;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
  color: #000;
}
ul#items li:hover {
  color: #333;
}
ol#pagination li {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cssglobe.com/lab/easypaginate/js/easypaginate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul id="items">
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
  <li>Page 4</li>
  <li>Page 5</li>
  <li>Page 6</li>
  <li>Page 7</li>
  <li>Page 8</li>
  <li>Page 9</li>
  <li>Page 10</li>
  <li>Page 11</li>
  <li>Page 12</li>
  <li>Page 13</li>
  <li>Page 14</li>
</ul>
```

[**Fonte e Documentação**](http://cssglobe.com/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination/)

---

Ou você também pode utilizar da API **Jquery Quick Pagination**.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="/paginaSYS">
      <h4>tituloMenuSYS1</h4>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/paginaSYS">
      <h4>tituloMenuSYS2</h4>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/paginaSYS">
      <h4>tituloMenuSYS3</h4>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/paginaSYS">
      <h4>tituloMenuSYS4</h4>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="/paginaSYS">
      <h4>tituloMenuSYS5</h4>
    </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT exemplo:**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("ul#menu").quickPagination({pageSize:"3"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4otefLc3/

**Referências:**

[Quick Pagination](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-quick-pagination-list-items/)
[Página do GitHub](https://github.com/jlafitte/jquery-quick-pagination)
[Exemplos](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/jquery-quick-pagination/)

Comment: A minha resposta é para implementação, ou seja uma ideia geral de como fazer.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Você está certo, gostei da resposta, vou deletar esse comentário idiota, me desculpe;

Comment: Excelente resposta @RafaelWithoeft, eu não votei nela,pois a outra já havia me servidor, muito obrigado

Comment: @FelipeStoker Sem problemas, só não dá para entender negativação se a solução não está errada.

Comment: Então, tinha mais postagem negativadas, eu não sei quem fez isso. de qualquer forma eu positivei novamente.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, foi um Troll que passou por aqui e negativou a todos e não deu justificativa.

Comment: @TobyMosque Bom de qualquer forma tentei melhorar e adequar mais ao que ele utilizaria...

Answer (score 2):

Já que você mencionou que terá apenas um `UL` com N (vários) `LI`, então você terá que ter algum mecanismo para controlar quais `LI` estarão visíveis.

O exemplo abaixo irei usar a propriedade **data-page** com `es`

```js
var page = 1;
var pageCount = 3
var btUp = $("#btUp");
var btDown = $("#btDown");

btDown.click(function () {
    var pageAtual = $(".menu li[data-page=" + page + "]");
    page = page + 1;
    var pageProx = $(".menu li[data-page=" + page + "]");
    
    console.log(pageAtual);
    
    pageAtual.toggleClass("hide");
    pageProx.toggleClass("hide");
    
    btUp.prop("disabled", false);
    if (page == pageCount) {
        btDown.prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

btUp.click(function () {
    var pageAtual = $(".menu li[data-page='" + page + "']");
    page = page - 1;
    var pageProx = $(".menu li[data-page='" + page + "']");
    
    pageAtual.toggleClass("hide");
    pageProx.toggleClass("hide");
    
    btDown.prop("disabled", false);
    if (page == 1) {
        btUp.prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;    
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina01">
        <h4>Pagina 01</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina02">
        <h4>Pagina 02</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina03">
        <h4>Pagina 03</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina04">
        <h4>Pagina 04</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina05">
        <h4>Pagina 05</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns" data-page="1">
      <a href="/pagina06">
        <h4>Pagina 06</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina07">
        <h4>Pagina 07</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina08">
        <h4>Pagina 08</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina09">
        <h4>Pagina 09</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina10">
        <h4>Pagina 10</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina11">
        <h4>Pagina 11</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="2">
      <a href="/pagina12">
        <h4>Pagina 12</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
      <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina13">
        <h4>Pagina 13</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina14">
        <h4>Pagina 14</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina15">
        <h4>Pagina 15</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina16">
        <h4>Pagina 16</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina17">
        <h4>Pagina 17</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="small-2 columns hide" data-page="3">
      <a href="/pagina18">
        <h4>Pagina 18</h4>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
    
<input id="btUp" class="button small" type="button" value="/\" disabled="disabled" />
<input id="btDown" class="button small" type="button" value="\/" />
```